# pleora sdk convert PvBuffer or PvRawData to QByteArray

Tags: qt

I'm using the pleora sdk to capture images from an external camera and I am able to successfully write the data to tiff image files on disk.  My next step is to change the data storage to SQLite instead of disk files.

I have PvBuffer *lBuffer pointer working fine.  Now I need to convert that data to a format I can use to write to SQLite.  I'm using Qt on linux so the QByteArray would be very convenient.

This is kind of a specific question for the pleora sdk and Qt.  I'm hoping someone has experience with this.

PvRawData *rawData = lBuffer->GetRawData();

QByteArray ba;

//Need to copy the data from rawData to ba.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer and wanted to post in case anybody else has something similar.  I uses the reintepret_cast method.

```
data = lBuffer->GetDataPointer()
imgSize = lBuffer->GetPayloadSize();
const char *d = reinterpret_cast<char *>(data);
QByteArray ba(d, imgSize);
QSqlQuery q = QSqlQuery( db );
q.prepare("INSERT INTO imgData (image) values (:imageData)");
q.bindValue(":imageData", ba);
if ( !q.exec() )
qDebug() << "Error inserting image into table: " << q.lastError() << endl;
else
qDebug() << "Query executed properly" << endl;
```